# Meaning of BRMC's song's title (0.0770833333333333)

Tags: lyrics, meaning, rock, song-title

I've been wondering for a while about what could **0.0770833333333333** mean? It's a song by Black Rebel Motorcycle Club, from *Beat The Devil's Tattoo* album. What I figured out so far is that `0.0770833333333333 = 37/480` assuming that it's actually `0.07708(3)`. I tried to gather any info about which ways the numbers could relate to anything but didn't find nothing.

Maybe someone has some thought on this?

Comment: Do you mean the song called "1:51"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsdDTcL8g1k. A post at http://howllr.tumblr.com/post/65518214498/ah-yes-my-favourite-black-rebel-motorcycle-club suggests that this title got mangled somewhere...

Comment: yeah, that's the song... even on the Google Music http://imgur.com/yqviQ9P Well, wiki says it's indeed called "1:51" and it's only on the bonus edition so I guess it has something to do with releasing policies or copyrights...